# Is there a name for a shape like this?

Tags: geometry, terminology

As part of my master's project in statistics, I have written some MATLAB code that takes as input a set of points in the unit hypercube of $\mathbb R^{1000}$ and outputs an indicator vector telling which of those points lie in a region $F$ which may be described as follows: In four of the dimensions, $F$ describes a hyperellipsoid (contained by the unit cube), and in the remaining 996 dimensions, $F$ fills the space.

So (just to illustrate): if $F$ were in $\mathbb R^3$ with a 2-dimensional ellipse (instead of $\mathbb R^{1000}$ with 4-d ellipse), then $F$ would be like an oblong cylinder, something ellipsoidal when viewed from above or below and with straight sides connecting the two ellipsoidal faces.

Is there anything in particular I can call $F$ (the 1000-d version)? Is it some sort of "hyperellipsoidal prism", or something?

Comment: It’s not my racket, but I’d call this shape a cylinder, using whatever adjective seems most appropriate to the situation.

Comment: I was about to say much the same thing. I think nobody is likely to be surprised or confused if you call it a cylinder, or a something something (4-ellipsoidal?) cylinder.

Comment: I wonder if the reader might expect a cylinder to be the product of an ellipsoid and a *one-dimensional* line segment, rather than (in this case) a box.